# IP address discovered

Tags: security

I signed up for Google plus and didn't realize it was downloading my Pictures automatically,
I was taking screenshots to send to someone to show them what my computer was saying in order to let them see, so they could tell me how to fix the problem. When I went to my Google account because it kept telling me to sync, I went to account settings,and found out that over 28,000 people had visited my site, I looked through my pictures and found that screenshot on the public to view. Now, I think 28,000 and more people have my static IP address. What do I do? How much information can they have and will it give them access to my computer.
thanks,
scared

Comment: Why do you think they have your IP? Was it on those screenshots?

Comment: My IP address was from my phone, and I have security cams in my house, and the secutity guy tried to hep me if an issue I had with my cams so My mobile phone has access to my cams, which require an IP static address, Goole plus auto's my photos, even screenshots, now I feel my cam's can be accessed. I'm worried everyone has access to my computer. I had no idea google was doing this, until I went to settings.

Comment: the screenshot was of my static IP address, after seeing 28,000 people viewing my google account, I wondered why, and I saw my screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

In two words: **don't worry.**

Unless you are being specifically targetted (in which case anyone who cares is likely to have your IP address already, or not need it, depending on the mode of attack), someone having seen an IP address is a curiosity at most.

More to the point, the vast majority of "bad stuff" on the Internet is non-targetted; automated software constantly scanning for vulnerable systems. If your system is vulnerable, it has likely been compromised long before those screenshots were posted, and if it's reasonably well protected, someone having your IP address won't really matter much.

If you are *really* worried, just call your ISP and have them assign you a new static IP address. But I don't think you have to worry.

Case in point: generally, simply sending an email (or browsing to a web page, by technical necessity) reveals your IP address to the recipient in the trace headers.

Of course, **do** go through those settings with a fine-toothed comb and make any adjustments you feel might be worthwhile. But that's a different matter and something which -- obviously -- should best have been done proactively, not reactively. (Better late than never, though.)

Comment: ok, thanks so much, this is very helpful. I will call our ISP. It was shocking to see 28,000 people viewing my account, I have deleted my google account and shut down all cams so far.

Comment: @Brenda If you found this answer helpful, please indicate so by upvoting and/or accepting. That is the customary way of saying thank you on the Stack Exchange network. See for example [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) in the Help Center.